# displaying a WPF Window from a System.Configuration.Install.Installer class

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

Greetings all,

I have a question.  I have created a WPF application.  So, I naturally created an installer (Visual Studio Install project)  for it.

In the Commit section of the installer I want to launch a WPF window which is my configuration wizard.

So I created a Installer class, overrode the Commit method and put the following in method:

`Application theApp = new Application;

theApp.Run (new MyWPFWizardWindow());`

I keep getting the error:
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

No problems, this makes as it is a GUI application.  But I can't, for the life of me, get the installer to fire up my window.  I have tried putting [STAThread] on the method.  I have tried firing up a thread and setting the ApartmentState to STA.  I am guessing it's something really simple that I am over looking.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks in advance..

cmb..

Comment: Can you provide code?How did you solve the problem?I try do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `AppartmentState` to STA *before* starting a thread should do the trick...

Try doing that, but instead of

```
new Application().Run(new MyWPFWizardWindow());
```

do

```
new MyWPFWizardWindow().ShowDialog();
```

... which is pretty similar, but doesn't create an instance of `Application` class (which you can't have more than one).

Comment: That seemed to work. I can show my window now.  Am running into other issues, but this solved that one issue.